# Use library classes written in Objective-c inside Swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-library

I have a Swift project in which i want to use an sdk which is in a form of library files .a and .h files (written in Objective-C)

How do i use the code inside my swift project?

When i add the files to my project it dont give the option to create an objective-c bridging header

Comment: Defines Module must be set to Yes in Build Settings, under Packaging.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097484/creating-a-bridging-header

Answer (score 0):

To create a bridging header:

1. Add a new Header file to your project. File -> New -> Header file. I named it: "Your-Header-file.h"
2. Go to your project Target -> Build Settings, search for Objective-C Bridging Header and set the header file's path in this field. You can do this by double-click Objective-C Bridging Header field, a panel show up, drag the header file to this panel.

[image]

3. include .h file you need to use in Your-Header-file.h.